# Android Tabs : Set main tab without starting the default fragment

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

I use this code to set the main tab :

```
tabhost.setCurrentTabByTag(...);
```

It's work fine but the problem that the default tab fragment start with the new tab which I set to current tab, I check that by :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);

    Log.e("LOG", "Default Fragment Start, ID = 0");
}
```

When I run the app I see in the logcat "Default Fragment Start, ID = 0", that mean although I set current tab, the default tab steal started when app run.

any suggestions to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with a trick, I add a tab on the first then I name it some thing like InitializationTab :

```
addTab("InitializationTab".....); // index 0
addTab("First"....); // index 1
addTab("Second"...); // index 2
addTab("Third"...); // index 3
addTab("Fourth"...); // index 4
```

Then I set current tab to any tab I want by

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
```

And I hide it by this code

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Now only one tab will started.

Why I did all that? because on the first when the app ran, two fragments was started in same time so that can make the app slow.